# PHP version on cloudControl

Tags: cloudcontrol

I see that at this moment, cloudControl PaaS is running on PHP 5.3.2, as I checked with phpinfo on my deployments.

If the PHP version is upgraded, will we be informed?  Is there a place where this type of information is posted?

Answer (score 4):

The PHP version is defined by the chosen stack. Currently available stacks at this point in time (Oct. 2013) are Luigi and Pinky. A new major PHP version would be available with the next stack and you can control per deployment which stack to use. This means you can upgrade the development deployment before migrationg production. You can find more information on the stacks in our documentation.

https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#stacks

Comment: It would be useful to have PHP version / stack mapping documented, so I didn't have to run my own experiments to determine what's what.

Comment: We provide both http://luigi-phpinfo.cloudcontrolled.com/ and http://pinky-phpinfo.cloudcontrolled.com/ for that purpose.